# How to check if id exists in the result return by SQL custom function (which returns SETOF table)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written SQL function which returns a row of `table abc` like this

```
(889d47f6-bc9c-4036-8808-4b9e74bb5ab9,"2020-10-22 05:13:36.626066+00","2020-11-12 05:57:51.792671+00",9afbca19-402e-4edb-ab5b-bdeef25fc797,"testing","testing",37f095ef-f4a9-41a8-a9d3-48ccc08c66ff,"testing",,t,"2020-12-12 05:13:10.601+00",t)
```

Then I want to use this returned row in a query to check if `id` exists in this returned row result. where `id` is first column.

Something like this,

```
select * from abc where abc.id not in (select function_name())
```

But this query is not working because it is returning column not id. How to fix this query?

Comment: What is `return type` of your function.

Comment: return type is SETSOF abc, where abc is table name

Answer (score 0):

If your function is returning the `SETOF` table `abc` then you can write your query like below:

```
select * from abc where abc.id not in (select id from function_name());
```

Here your function is returning the structure of your table `abc`. So you can treat it as a table.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6fb1a90587e7916f55928b83a3ea7109)

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists`:

```
select *
from abc
where not exists (select 1
                  from function_name() f
                  where f.id = abc.id 
                 );
```